# .htaccess redirect specific domain to specific page

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I want any traffic coming from urlnumberone.com and urlnumbertwo.com to redirect to a couple of specific pages on my site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www.\.)?urlnumberone\.com
RewriteRule ^$ /thepath/tomypage/goeshere/ [L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www.\.)?urlnumbertwo\.com
RewriteRule ^$ /thesecond/pathgoeshere/ [L]
```

Right now, both URLs are simply taking the user to the homepage on my site, rather than going to the pages I've intended. What am I doing wrong? In case it matters, the site is a WordPress site and the WordPress rules are UNDER these redirects, not above them in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are two issues. There is an extra dot in the `RewriteCond` lines, so the portion in parentheses currently means "www(any-character)(literal-dot)", which would prevent matching the www version of the domain that you need to match -- unless you're trying to match domains like `www6.urlnumberone.com` and `www3.urlnumberone.com`.

So, I would replace:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www.\.)?urlnumberone\.com`

With:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www\.)?urlnumberone\.com`

Next, for the `RewriteRule` line, I would change the `^$` (replacing an empty string) with `.*` (replacing the whole path), and use a 302 or 301 redirect. Since WordPress rewrites every URL that isn't an existing file or directory, it's easy to make redirect loops by mistake, so using a 301 or 302 should help prevent that. So I would use:

`RewriteRule .* /thepath/tomypage/goeshere/ [R=302,L]`

There may be mod_rewrite wizards out there that have a better answer, but this method works well in my experience.