# Redirect to specific page from specific page if mobile

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect

I've been looking at this answer here and it seems possible to redirect to a page if detected that the user is using a mobile device.

However, is it possible to redirect to a specific URL if we can detect that the user is on a mobile device? From the .htaccess file

Just to note I am enforcing HTTPS.

e.g.

- IF is_mobile && is_page 'shop' - REDIRECT to 'mobileshop'
- IF is mobile & is page 'home' - REDIRECT to 'mobilehome'

It seems as if you can redirect specific domains to pages with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42988471/htaccess-redirect-specific-domain-to-specific-page)...but not sure how to also apply it to only trigger if device is mobile?

```
    RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www.\.)?urlnumberone\.com
RewriteRule ^$ /thepath/tomypage/goeshere/ [L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www.\.)?urlnumbertwo\.com
RewriteRule ^$ /thesecond/pathgoeshere/ [L]
```

Comment: are you looking for .htaccess redirection only?
Or this can be achieved using Javascript.

Comment: No any solution :) - I have been using a redirection plugin, but it's stopped working. So I thought modifying at server level would have priority.

Comment: I see, if any solution can work then adding this code might help. 
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (screen.width <= 699) {
document.location = "mobilepageurl";
}
//-->
</script>

To make it more dynamic, you can add custom field to pages and pass url from custom fields to mobileurl :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript code for that

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (screen.width <= 699 ) {
    if(window.location.pathname == '/strongshop')
    {
        document.location = "/strongshopmobile";
    }
}
//-->
</script>
```

You can later combine it with Custom field or programming logic to make it more advanced & dynamic

Comment: How to add in the rules? So if URL B, redirect to mobile version URL A....If URL B, redirect to mobile version URL B

Comment: You can easily detect the current url using javascript [window.location.hostname] and use if condition along with it, 
I hope this helps, or just give me what exactly you want, I can write  a quick code for you.

Comment: If you could give example of one URL: /strongshop/ to /strongshopmobile/ - I can duplicate?

Comment: Updated answer, window.location.pathname help us in retrieving the page name from url.

Comment: So I have another issue. Forcing HTTPS prevents redirects happening on my site. I'm not sure how to get these working together. Another question perhaps

Comment: You can use trigger function as click for redirection.

Comment: Sorry, im not sure what you mean, could you explain?